# Pharo is re-writing code after compilation

Tags: pharo

I am going through the book "Learning Object-Oriented Programming, Design and TDD with Pharo" by Ducasse and Pollet.

I am using a Pharo 8.0.0 image as reported on the world help menu.

After method compilation by accepting code in the browser, Pharo seems to be re-writing my code by substituting my method arguments and method variables with "arg1" and "tmp1."  How can I keep my code from being re-written?

Here's an example re-write from chapter 7:

```
detectAllMissingLettersFor: arg1
    | tmp1 |
    tmp1 := Set new.
    arg1
        do: [ :arg2 | 
            (self includes: arg2)
                ifFalse: [ tmp1 add: arg2 ] ].
    ^ tmp1
```

Pharo also re-wrote:

```
GramCheckerTest >> testIsPalindrome    
    self assert: 'ete' isPalindrome.  
    self assert: 'kayak' isPalindrome.  
    self deny: 'etat' isPalindrome.
```

as

```
GramCheckerTest >> testIsPalindrome  
self  
    assert: 'ete' isPalindrome;  
    assert: 'kayak' isPalindrome;  
    deny: 'etat' isPalindrome.
```

Why is Pharo re-writing code and how do I turn it off?

Comment: You have an installation problem. For some reason Pharo is not locating the sources so it does what it can, which is decompile the method for you to look at it in the most reasonably way given the circumstances. I would retry the installation (sorry, I'm not a Pharo user so I can't be more concrete here).

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia Thanks. I did try to change the file system directory of my image. Maybe that resulted in the image not being able to find the sources.

Comment: the .changes file must be located (I presume) in the same directory of the .image file. Try `Smalltalk changesFile fullName` and `Smalltalk imageFile fullName` to see where Pharo expects to find the .changes.

Comment: Hello, you should find the solution in the menu "Pharo->Settings->Code Browsing->QualityAssitant->Toggle rules to run"

Comment: As @LeandroCaniglia mentioned, the sources file was missing. I probably didn't include the sources file when I moved the image file to a new directory.  To fix the problem, I just created a new Pharo 9.0.0 image from the template library, moved my git repository and then loaded the objects. This fixed the problem and I know that my new image is consistent.